# Post is not liking or Disliking

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am making a Blog app and I built a Like or Dislike Feature BUT that is not working. It is showing custom error.

detail.html

```
                <form method="GET" class="likeForm d-inline" action="{% url 'comments:post_like_dislike' post.id %}"
                    data-pk="{{post.id}}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                        <span id="id_likes{{post.id}}">
                            {% if user in post.likes.all %}
                            <p style="color:#065FD4;display: inline">{{post.likes.count}}</p>
                            {% else %}
                            <p style="color:black;display: inline">{{post.likes.count}}</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        </span>
                        Like</button>
                </form>
                <form action="{% url 'comments:post_like_dislike' post.id %}" method="GET"
                    class="d-inline dislikeForm" data-pk="{{ post.id }}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i>
                        <span id="id_dislikes{{post.id}}">
                            {% if user in post.dislikes.all %}
                            <p style="color:#065FD4; display: inline;">{{post.dislikes.count}}</p>
                            {% else %}
                            <p style="color:black; display: inline;">{{post.dislikes.count}}</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        </span>
                        Dislike
                    </button>
                </form>
```

**ERROR**

When i click on Like button it shows me "Something went Wrong ( as a error message ) BUT doesn't count the Likes". When i click like through Admin, it counts and it shows in Browser page. BUT not when i click manually on Like button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending any `like` or `dislike` information when submitting the form. You should add name and value attribute like this in the button:

```
<form>
    <button name='submit' type='submit' value="like"> Like </button>
</form>
<form>
   <button name='submit' type='submit' value="dislike"> Dislike </button>
</form>
```

FYI, as you are doing database updates, it is better to use `POST` method. Because GET methods should be idempotent, meaning they should not change the state of the server.

Finally, as you have two different forms, I think it is better to have two different views to handle these operations(one for like and another for dislike).